# What is wrong with my solution? Splitting the set [n] into non-empty intervals and choosing a non-empty subset from these intervals

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to solve this problem for my combinatorics class. Here is the problem:

Let $h_n$ be the number of ways to split the set [n] into some number of non-empty intervals and choose a non-empty subset from the set of these intervals. Show that $h_n$ = $2(3)^{n-1}$.

I tried to solve this problem using generating functions.

Here is my attempt so far:

I will use the product rule of generating functions. Let $F_{split}(x)$ be the generating function of splitting the set [n] into some number of non-empty intervals, and let $G_{choosing subset}(x)$ be the generating function of choosing a non-empty subset from the set of these intervals.

Then, $K(x) = F_{split}(x) \times G_{choosing subset}(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} (h_n)x^n$. I want to find $K(x)$, then find the coefficient of $x^n$ so I can find $h_n$.

$F_{split}(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} (2^n-1)x^n$ = $\sum_{n\geq0} (2x)^n - \sum_{n\geq0} (x)^n$

$= (\frac{1}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x})$

and

$G_{choosing subset}(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} (2^{n-1})x^n$

$= \frac{\sum_{n\geq0} (2x)^n}{2}$

$= \frac{1}{2(1-2x)}$

Then,

$K(x) = \frac{1}{2-4x}\times(\frac{1}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{1-x})$

Now, applying partial fraction decomposition:

$= \frac{1-x}{(2-4x)(1-2x)(1-x)} - \frac{1-2x}{(2-4x)(1-x)(1-2x)}$

$= \frac{x}{(2-4x)(1-2x)(1-x)}$

Then,

$\frac{A}{2-4x}+\frac{B}{1-2x}+\frac{C}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(2-4x)(1-2x)(1-x)}$

But I cannot solve this equation because I have 3 unknown variables with 2 equations. So I just get:

$A+2B=-1$ and $C=\frac{1}{2}$

I would appreciate any hint or help!

Comment: I think that the claimed answer, $h_n=2\cdot 3^{n-1}$, is incorrect. We should have $h_1=1$, because there is only one way to split a one-element set into intervals, and then choose a nonempty subset from each interval. However, $2\cdot 3^{\color{blue}1-1}=2$. Did you copy the problem correctly?

Comment: BTW, the reason your partital fractions are not working out is that you did not fully simplify your fraction. Note that $$\frac{x}{(2-4x)(1-2x)(1-x)}=\frac{x}{2(1-2x)^2(1-x)}.$$Therefore, the partial fractions will be $$\frac{A}{1-2x}+\frac{B}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{C}{1-x}.$$

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for the reply! Yes, my professor's notes say that it is $2(3)^{n-1}$. I see why my partial fraction was not working. Also, is it OK to use ordinary generating functions in this case, or should I have done exponential generating functions?

Comment: $2\cdot 3^{n-1}$ is the number of ways to split $[n]$ into nonempty intervals, and then to choose an **arbitrary** subset of the intervals. If you replace arbitrary with **nonempty**, like you wrote in your question, then the correct answer is $2\cdot 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$. So, there is still a mistake in your post; I do not know if the mistake is with the question, or the answer.

Comment: What is "the set $[n]$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is quite tricky to make this work with generating functions. Here is the best I can do.

For each $n,k\ge 1$, let $f_{n,k}$ be the number of ways to split a list of length $n$ into exactly $k$ nonempty intervals. You can prove that $f_{n,k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. There are $n-1$ spaces between the $n$ entries of the list; you need to select $k-1$ of these spaces, and break the list at the selected spaces.

Let $F(x,t)$ be the bivariate generating function for $f_{n,k}$.
$$
\begin{align}
F(x,t)&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k=1}^n f_{n,k}\,x^nt^k
\\&=\sum_{n\ge 1}x^n \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}t^{k}
\\&=\sum_{n\ge 1}x^n t(1+t)^{n-1}
\\&=\frac{xt}{1-x(1+t)}.
\end{align}
$$
Why is this useful? Your question is about splitting the list into nonempty sublists, and then choosing a nonempty subset of those sublists. This means that the answer to your question is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f_{n,k}\cdot (2^k-1)
$$
This explains why we needed to keep track of $k$, the number of intervals. The number of ways to choose a nonempty subset of intervals depends on the number of intervals.

We can write the answer to this question in terms of $F(x,t)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n f_{n,k}\cdot (2^k-1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f_{n,k}\cdot 2^k-\sum_{k=1}^n f_{n,k}\cdot 1^k
\\&=[x^n]\Big(F(x,2)-F(x,1)\Big)
\\&=[x^n]\left(\frac{2x}{1-3x}-\frac{x}{1-2x}\right)
\\&= \boxed{2\cdot 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}}
\end{align}
$$
The final answer to your question, as written, is $2\cdot 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$, and is **not** $2\cdot 3^{n-1}$, as your professor claims.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easier way to solve this question, since as you've pointed out, the process for generating functions seem a bit tedious.

Comment: See Empy2's excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

You multiply the generating functions when $h_n=\sum f_ig_{n-i}$, which isn't in this case.
To get powers of $3$, you need $1-3x$ in the denominator, and can't get there by multiplying those of $f$ and $g$.
Here is another way to count:  $1$ is either chosen or not in the final collection.  Then $i+1$ has three options:  attach it to the same interval as $i$; start a new interval that will be chosen; or start a new interval that won't be chosen.
So $2×3^{n-1}$ is the count when the collection of intervals chosen may be empty.